2 observables declared with takeUntilDestroyed, when combined, require additional takeUntilDestroyed?
I'm using takeUntilDestroyed to manage my subscriptions and avoid memory leaks. Within an injection context, variable declaration, I will have something like this
mySubject1$ = new BehaviourSubject<void>(void 0);
myData1$ = mySubject1$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(), switchMap(() => myService.getData1()));
mySubject2$ = new BehaviourSubject<void>(void 0);
myData2$ = mySubject2$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(), switchMap(() => myService.getData2()));

In my constructor I want to combine these, do I need to use takeUntilDestroyed() again?
constructor(){
combineLatest([myData1$, myData2$]).pipe(takeUntilDestroyed())...
}


You don't need takeUntilDestroyed on the service, you need to add it on the subscription of the component (my point being the components are destroyed often, not services).
But it looks like, the combineLatest will be unsubscribed, when the service is destroyed, but if you have providedIn: 'root' on the service, it's never destroyed.
So, keep the take until destroyed on the component level, to prevent problems.
mySubject1$ = new BehaviourSubject<void>(void 0);
myData1$ = mySubject1$.pipe(switchMap(() => myService.getData1()));
mySubject2$ = new BehaviourSubject<void>(void 0);
myData2$ = mySubject2$.pipe(switchMap(() => myService.getData2()));

In the component
constructor(){
    combineLatest([myData1$, myData2$]).pipe(takeUntilDestroyed())...
}


I'd say the best would be to call takeUntilDestroyed only in places where you call an actual subscribe. There's no need to call takeUntilDestroyed in observables that are only subscribed to using the async pipe or get combined into a different observable.
takeUntilDestroyed is a way to cleanup a subscription but it is an operator that does not really know where the subscription happens. The best place would be to call it right before you subscribe to the observable.
